# grunt-injector - how to use Grunt's 'dynamically built files objects.'?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Grunt's dynamically built files objects is in the structure of:

```
files: [
        {
          expand: true,     // Enable dynamic expansion.
          cwd: 'lib/',      // Src matches are relative to this path.
          src: ['**/*.js'], // Actual pattern(s) to match.
          dest: 'build/',   // Destination path prefix.
          ext: '.min.js',   // Dest filepaths will have this extension.
          extDot: 'first'   // Extensions in filenames begin after the first dot
        },
]
```

But this format does not work in grunt-injector:

```
injector: {
    options: {
    destFile : 'app/static/index.html',
    ignorePath: 'app/'
    }, 
    local_dependencies: {
    files:  [
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'app/static/css/',
            src: ['*.css'],
            dest: '/static/css',
            ext: '.css'
            ]  
    }  
},
```

Any suggestions on how I can use Grunt's specific 'dynamically built files objects' with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone has this issue, I guess you can not use sub categories like local_dependencies.

This worked for me:

```
    injector: {
        options: {
        destFile : 'app/static/index.html',
        ignorePath: 'app/'
        }, 
            files: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'app/static/css/',
                src: ['*.css'],
                dest: 'app/static/css',
                ext: '.css'
                }
    },
```